# Why am I getting a "failed to connect to server" message from tmux when I try to list sessions?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, tmux

Here's what's happening to me: I start tmux sessions using `tmux -L name1`, `tmux -L name2`; then I detatch them using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. Then I try to get a list of the currently running sessions on my computer. However, when I run `tmux ls`, I get an error message:

```
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
```

Is this a bug? I'm familiar with screen; I regard `screen -ls` as a very useful function since I might start a session and leave it running for weeks before the next time I attach to it. Because of this, the ability to list current running tmux sessions is quite important for me. Why does `tmux ls` return a "connection refused" error when I know tmux is running?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try `tmux -L name1 list-session`.

Comment: This command will only list the `name1` session and not `name2`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25969889/1248175) for a way to list multiple sessions.

Comment: The **first** word of the question is "Why". That answer doesn't even try to deliver. Plus that command actually failed in my case (however, `tmux -L list-session` magically worked - now I have to dig myself to know why, why not the former, how, etc. So basically I have to answer OP's question for myself).

Comment: @whyisyoung Unfortunately SO doesn't allow to unvote comments after a few minutes. But your comment is highly misleading. What you are doing with `tmux -L list-session` is to **START A NEW** instance of tmux, with a socket named `list-session`. This is utterly misleading, as the command reads: "use tmux to list the sessions with the flag -L set". You should delete that comment (since you can't edit anymore), given how harmful it is.

Comment: @7heo.tk Sorry I cannot remember what happened at that time. Then I tried the command `tmux -L list-session`, it indeed start a new **instance**, not **session**.  thanks for your comment.

Comment: @whyisyoung thank you for your cleanup; it is cool to see that SO's content improves over time. (Unrelated: for the people who read the comments above; I answered OP's question for everyone (not only myself) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30211312))

Answer (score 82):

**TL;DR:** Try sending `SIGUSR1` signal to the tmux server process.

In my case, after about 8 days of inactivity, I was not able to reattach:

```
$ tmux attach
no sessions
```

However, a grep for tmux process got me this output:

```
$ ps -aef | fgrep -i tmux
hari     7139     1  1  2016 ?        2-20:32:31 tmux
hari    25943 25113  0 22:00 pts/0    00:00:00 fgrep --color=auto -i tmux
```

As suggested by @7heo.tk, this indicates that tmux server is still running, but `tmux ls` was giving `failed to connect to server: Connection refused` error. I verified that the tmp directory that belonged to the tmux session existed and `lsof -p 7139` (the pid of tmux server) showed that the socket file is open:

```
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
tmux    7139 hari    5u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0 1712879255 /tmp/tmux-50440/default
```

I also tried explicitly specifying the `-S /tmp/tmux-50440/default` to tmux but it didn't help. However, I read in the tmux man page that sending `SIGUSR1` would make tmux recreate the socket file, so I tried that and I was able to immediately find the session and reattach:

```
$ kill -s USR1 7139
$ tmux ls
0: 12 windows (created Mon Apr 18 21:17:55 2016) [198x62]
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I did the foolish thing of performing an `rm -rf tmp/*` which removed the tmux socket file. I will definitely remeber this trick.

Comment: This solved my problem too: I had changed an idiotic default setting of $TMP, which meant the tmux socket was in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this solved the problem for me too. Could you maybe elaborate on what's happening here and why this fix is necessary?

Comment: @Harpe I don't know, probably a tmux bug that is not easily reproducible.

Comment: the easier one-liner to accomplish this at once would be: `pkill -USR1 -xf tmux` (at least if you started the tmux server with its plain `tmux` command.)

Comment: or possibly `pkill -USR1 -o tmux` should also work and even if you didn't use just the plain `tmux` command to start its server.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked!! Thanks lot @haridsv

Comment: Which of the commands in your answer is it that sends a `SIGUSR1` signal to the tmux server process?

Comment: `kill -s USR1` is the one that sends the `SIGUSR1` signal to the process.

Answer (score 34):

This happens to me when I do not have any sessions running.  I'm just starting to use tmux and didn't realize that if you restart your computer you lose your sessions which surprised me at first.

For those of you who are thinking the same thing: [Restore tmux session after reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/440015/restore-tmux-session-after-reboot).  A summary of the post: Use shell scripts to build your tmux sessions or create a fancy [shell history tracker](http://blog.edsantiago.com/articles/tmux-session-preserve/).

Comment: FYI: tmux sessions don't get saved after reboot because they are simply background processes that will end when the computer turns off.

Comment: not really an accurate answer because the OP said nothing about a reboot, but nevertheless a nice link to a good question very with useful ideas & links.

Comment: I mentioned the reboot @DJCrashdummy because that's how I ran into the problem. Maybe the OP rebooted or maybe they didn't. Answers on SO don't have to be accurate. The hope is to be helpful to the greater community.

Answer (score 19):

You get this error indeed if there are no session open. If there are no sessions open there is no tmux server running so it can't connect to it.

With the `-L` option, you change the socket name the tmux server uses, it's not a way to name your sessions. You better use the following commands:

```
tmux new -s name1
tmux new -s name2
```

These will create 2 sessions on a server with the default socket name. Now you can do:

```
$ tmux ls
name1: 1 windows (created Mon Sep 22 10:34:40 2014) [158x40] (attached)
name2: 1 windows (created Mon Sep 22 10:34:43 2014) [158x40] (attached)
```

And you see all the sessions running on the server on the default socket. You can reattach one of them using:

```
tmux attach -d -s name1
```

`-s` specifies the name of the session
`-d` will detach it from it's previous client (if it is attached)

You can also switch between sessions inside tmux with the `choose-tree` command which by default is assigned to the keystroke  `C-s` (prefix key + s). This is what I usually do.

Answer (score 19):

This happened to me when the Ubuntu desktop crashed and my gnome-terminal windows exited. I could still see the tmux process was running (`ps aux | grep tmux`) but for some reason tmux commands would not work to list the existing sessions. Apparently it wasn't finding the existing Unix socket of the still-running tmux process. The fix in this scenario is to locate the existing Unix socket and specify that to tmux using the `-S` flag; here's how:

You can find the PID of your still-running tmux process with this:

```
ps -p $(pidof tmux)
```

Now take your PID (in my case, 6876) and run this to list any open Unix sockets:

```
sudo lsof -Uap 6876
```

Hopefully you see output like this:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
tmux    6876  abe    3u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0 408477 socket
tmux    6876  abe    4u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0 408478 socket
tmux    6876  abe    6u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0 408479 /tmp/tmux-1000/default
```

Now you can specify that existing Unix socket to your tmux command (using the `-S` flag), and you should be able to list-sessions and attach properly:

```
tmux -S /tmp/tmux-1000/default list-sessions
tmux -S /tmp/tmux-1000/default attach -t 0
```

Answer (score 9):

You may have an error in your `.tmux.conf`. I had this problem until i took out this line from my `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

You could also try `tmux -v` and then look at the logs it prints.

Comment: Where does it print the logs? should it be console output?

Answer (score 6):

One easy fix is to delete the tmp files left by the tmux server, for example, by doing `$ rm -rf /tmp/tmux-xxx/`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution for me. The next step is just to create a new session with `tmux new -s $session_name` and that's all.

Answer (score 6):

The way `TMUX(1)` works is by having a client process (`tmux`) connect to a server process (`tmux` too, but not attached to a TTY), as shown in the following `ps` output:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
19229 pts/1    S+     0:00 tmux
19231 ?        Ss     0:00 tmux
```

That shows that the client actually starts before the server (one could assume it forks it).

---

After detach/re-attach, the same `ps` command outputs:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
19231 ?        Ss     0:00 tmux
19290 pts/1    S+     0:00 tmux attach
```

This shows the tmux client as `tmux attach`, thus being a bit easier to understand.

---

Now, if we look at the output of `pstree` in both of the above cases, we get in both cases (ignoring the `pid` change for `tmux attach`):

```
pstree -p
init(1)─┬─acpid(1824)
        ├─cron(1859)
        ⋮
        ├─sh(14146)───tmux(19229)
        └─tmux(19231)───sh(19233)───pstree(19234)
```

Clearly showing that the commands typed (`pstree` in this case) in the client process (PID `19229`) get executed by the server one (PID `19231`), thus allowing them to continue without [SIGHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals) in the event where the client terminal is lost (over ssh, for example).

---

Now, to the question OP asked: what happens in the case where `tmux` returns `failed to connect to server: Connection refused` is that the server process (pid 19231 in our case) is unreachable, whatever the reason (it can be because the server process died; but also because the user executing the `tmux` client doesn't have the permissions to access the tmux socket, etc.)

The solution in that case is to `grep` for the `tmux` processes (via `ps` for example), and pray that you didn't get this error because the server died (so you can attach to it by using `lsof` to get what sockets it listens to). Otherwise, there is no way to *attach* to the server, as it is as dead as after a reboot.

---

### TL;DR:

This error can be given for multiple reasons, ranging from bug to critical failure (program died). In a nutshell, use the UNIX tools at your disposal to determine what socket does `tmux` use, if it is still running (there should be at least two processes if you have the tmux client running - that happens after invoking `tmux` or `tmux attach` from the shell) and thus if you lost your session or not.

*Note: as other answers pointed out, if the reason for this error to be shown is a socket error, you can use the `-L` flag to tell `tmux` to use a specific socket.*

Answer (score 3):

This may happen if you or any cleaning process delete files in `/tmp/*`. All your sessions data are lost if you can't recover those files. Killing all tmux instances and restart it is the only choice left, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I was using another program inside of tmux (reattach-to-user-namespace), and I was getting this error when I switched computers because reattach-to-user-namespace was not installed. The fix was to simply run `brew install reattach-to-user-namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I ran tmux with another user (was root), and I tried to list sessions with my normal user..
So you might want to check the user with which you ran your tmux first.
To do so:

```
$ ps -aef | fgrep -i tmux
root     7139     1  1  2016 ?        2-20:32:31 tmux
centos    25943 25113  0 22:00 pts/0    00:00:00 fgrep --color=auto -i tmux
```

See the username in the first column: here it's `root`